# Build docker image with terraform push it to ECR repo getting provisioner "local-exec" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, dockerfile, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ecr

I have written terraform file to create ecr repo and build the docker image and push it to ecr repo and in build argument I have given github token and that token has been created as github action secrets.  The intention is build argument which is mentioned in terraform has to pick the token from githubaction secrets.

```
    data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}
    locals {
      account_id    = data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id
      ecr_repo_name = "ecr-repo"
      ecr_image_tag = "latest"
    }
    resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repo" {
      name = local.ecr_repo_name
    }
    resource "null_resource" "ecr_image" {
      triggers = {
        docker_file = md5(file("${path.module}/../docker/Dockerfile"))
      }
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<EOF
            aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${local.account_id}.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
            cd ${path.module}/../docker
            docker build -t ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:${local.ecr_image_tag} --build-arg cms_git_token="${{ secrets.CMS_GIT_TOKEN }}" .
            docker images
            docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:${local.ecr_image_tag}
            
        EOF
      }
    }
    
    
When I run this terraform code I am getting error like "Error: local-exec provisioner error" can anyone help me on this.
    
 Error: local-exec provisioner error
│ 
│   with null_resource.ecr_image,
│   on ecr.tf line 14, in resource "null_resource" "ecr_image":
│   14:   provisioner "local-exec" {
│ 
│ Error running command '        aws ecr get-login***
│ eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin
│ ***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
│         cd ./../src
│         docker build -t ***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/retention-analysis-repo:latest .
│         docker images
│         docker push ***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/retention-analysis-repo:latest
│ ': exit status 1. Output: WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted
│ in /home/runner/.docker/config.json.
│ Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
│ https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
```

Comment: What's the full error message? Share the text, not a screenshot

Comment: Also, unless a copy paste error, you probably don't want a new line before the closing EOF.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: @Foo Error: local-exec provisioner error with null_resource.ecr_image, on ecr.tf line 14,in resource "null_resource" "ecr_image":14: provisioner "local-exec" { Error running command ' aws ecr get-login*** eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin│***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  cd ./../src  docker build -t ***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/retention-analysis-repo:latest-retention  .  docker push ***.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/retention-analysis-repo:latest-retention' : exit status 1 Outpu: WARNING ur passwd will b stored unencrypte in /home/runner/.docker/config.json

Comment: @MarkoE I have removed line before the closing EOF but still getting the same error.

Comment: The error message should be posted inside the question, not as a comment. Please edit your question including the error message.

Answer (score -1):

@Rajeev , Try this , working for me.

```
resource "null_resource" "ecr_image" {
  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.repo]
  triggers = {
    docker_file = md5(file("${path.module}/../../DOCKER/docker-sample-nginx/Dockerfile"))
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash" ,"-c"]
    command = "docker images && docker build -t ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:v1 ${path.module}/../../DOCKER/docker-sample-nginx/ && docker images && docker login --username AWS --password `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1` 1####99292.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com && docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:v1"
  }
}
```